# AccessViolationException with Awesomium generating a bitmap for XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, system.drawing, awesomium

I am trying to render the Awesomium headless browser in a BackgroundWorker.

However, when i try to copy the buffer using CopyTo, 
i get an AccessViolationException saying that i am trying to access protected memory. 
This is my first time using the System.Drawing namespace.

Here is my code:

```
            RenderBuffer b = browser.Render();
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0,size.Width, size.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
            b.CopyTo(bmd.Scan0, bmd.Stride, 4, false, false);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
            System.IO.MemoryStream dat = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 4);
            bmp.Save(dat, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            page = Texture2D.FromStream(Game.GraphicsDevice, dat);
            bmp.Dispose();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the bitmap size is incorrect and Awesomium is overflowing the buffer?

Comment: I have them set to the same XNA rectangle. I heard that this exception must have happened with unmanaged code (Awesomium)

Comment: Check the Width and Height of the RenderBuffer to see if it matches the size you used.

Comment: Yes, it is in the unmanaged code, and it's because the CopyTo is calling the native Awesomium functions, and the most probable cause of that exception is a buffer overflow, because that the check of the size

Comment: I'll check the rest of the code to make sure the browser is initializing right